# PyQt на Windows 10 остается зеленая рамка вокруг окна приложения

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt

Создал в Qt Designer свое окно , убрал стандартное окно Windows и сделал фон прозрачным с помощью :

```
self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

на Windows 7 все нормально на Windows 10  вокруг приложения зеленая рамка вместо системной толщиной в миллиметр.

Версии: python 3.4 PyQT 5.5 . Использовал pyinstaller -w -F что бы собрать exe файл.

Comment: если работает в одном месте, но ведёт себя по другому в другом месте, то стоит упомянуть версии используемого ПО: python, PyQT.

Comment: python 3.4  PyQT 5.5 . Использовал     pyinstaller -w -F что бы собрать exe файл.

Comment: а если без `pyinstaller` запустить?